# function with floor - differentiable?

Tags: calculus

**Question**:
Calculate the derivatives of the following functions (specify domain):

a. $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor \sin^2(\pi x)$

b. {$x^2 $}$\sin^2(\pi x)$

**What I did:**

on a. If $x \in \Bbb N$ then the function equals 0 (because of the sine). If $x \notin \Bbb N$ then I need to calculate the limit $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}h$ which I'm having trouble calculating, as both the numerator and denominator are going to be 0.

on b. I divided to the same cases and when x is an integer it's also 0. But this time I think I can just say that it's differentiable for $x \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb N$ and simply remove the braces in my calculation. Am I correct?

Comment: Is that greatest integer function?

Comment: floor is greatest integer below x. {} is the same as x-floor(x)

Comment: For $ n < x < n+1 $ both of floor and fractional part of $x^2$ have discontinuities.

Comment: could you please elaborate

Comment: A good first step to this problem would be: draw a picture!

Comment: For example, if $ 2\leqslant x<3 $ then $4 \leqslant x^2<9,$ so $\{\sqrt{5},\ \sqrt{6},\ \sqrt{7},\ \sqrt{8}\}\subset(2,\ 3)$ and
$$\lfloor x^2 \rfloor=\begin{cases}4,& 2\leqslant x<\sqrt{5}, \\
5,& \sqrt{5}\leqslant x<\sqrt{6},\\
6,& \sqrt{6}\leqslant x<\sqrt{7},\\
7,& \sqrt{7}\leqslant x<\sqrt{8}, \\
8,& \sqrt{8}\leqslant x<3.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some comments on your work so far:

- For part (a), your observation that the function is $0$ when $x \in \mathbb{N}$ is true, but irrelevant.  You don't care about the function's value -- you only care about its derivative, and whether or not it exists.
- For part (b), you are incorrect (though I think you may mean something different than what you said).  Again you cannot rule out the case $x \in \mathbb{N}$ simply by observing that the function takes on the value $0$.  Moreover, the function is *not* differentiable in *all* of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$.

Now, here are some hints.

- For part (a), note that if $a^2 \in \mathbb{N}$, then $f(x) = \lfloor x^2 \rfloor \sin^2 (\pi x)$ is not continuous at $x = a$ (why?); therefore, $f$ is not differentiable at $x = a$.
  Then, in the case where $a^2 \not \in \mathbb{N}$, observe that $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor$ *is constant* on a some small interval containing $a$.
  Therefore, you can just treat $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor$ as a constant when computing $f'(a)$.
- For part (b), you can take an easy shortcut.  Just write

$$
\{x^2\}\sin^2(\pi x) = x^2 \sin^2(\pi x) - \lfloor x^2 \rfloor \sin^2(\pi x)
$$

You know the derivative of $x^2 \sin^2(\pi x)$ and that it exists everywhere.  Also, you know the derivative of $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor \sin^2(\pi x)$ and exactly when it exists.  So you should be done.

Comment: for part (a) what your saying about calculating $f'(a)$ - should I do it with the limit definition? I don't know what is the limit of the expression I get there...

Comment: @user1685224 So, you shouldn't need the limit definition.  Since $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor$ is constant in the small interval you're worried about, you only need to know the derivative of $\sin^2(\pi x)$.  Do you know how to compute the derivative of $\sin^2 (\pi x)$?

Comment: Without the limit definition yes, But I thought I need to prove it using the limit definition. Or maybe I'm missing out on what is the justification that allowes me to use the "regular" derivative of sin.

Comment: @user1685224 Using the limit definition is gross!  It's just chain rule.  $\frac{d}{dx} \sin^2(\pi x) = \frac{d}{dx} (\sin(\pi x))^2$, and then note that $\frac{d}{dx} u^2 = 2u \frac{du}{dx}$.  Does this help?

Comment: I mean I know the derivative exists at the non-integer $a$ you offered, only if the limit $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin^2(\pi (x+h))-\sin^2(\pi x)}h$ (definition) exists. How can I make sure that the (gross) limit really exists?

Comment: You don't have to go all the way back to the limit definition every time you want the derivative to exist.  This would be a pain, which is why tools like the product rule and chain rule were developed.  The chain rule theorem says that if $f(x)$ is differentiable and $g(x)$ is differentiable, then $f(g(x))$ is differentiable too.  In particular, let $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = \sin(\pi x)$.

Comment: Okay, now I'm convinced ! Thanks!

Comment: and just to make sure - we divided into these two cases to show that on $a^2 \in \Bbb N$ the function is not differentiable because it's not continuous, and otherwise it is differentiable due to the chain rule?

Comment: @user1685224 yes, that is correct.